# Automate file transfer activity from local machine to remote machine using WinSCP script

Tags: windows, batch-file, sftp, winscp

I want to transfer file(s) in bulk (approx 50 files at a time) from my local machine to remote machine (Linux server) and I wanted to automate this activity using WinSCP.

I already have generated code by doing manually in WinSCP. Saved the code and created batch file. But it is throwing error like

> The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect
>
> The system cannot find the path specified.

However the given destination and source are valid/correct.

```
@echo

"open sftp://XXXXXXXXXXXXXX/ -hostkey=""ssh-rsa XXXX gk:op:09:n8:00:44:32:00:11:bn:mm:pp:45:bh:03:ea"""
"lcd C:\Users\007\Documents\testdata"
"cd /XXX/XXX/XXX/testdata"
"put *"
"exit"

set WINSCP_RESULT=%ERRORLEVEL%
if %WINSCP_RESULT% equ 0 (
  echo Success
) else (
  echo Error
)

exit /b %WINSCP_RESULT%
```

Answer (score 0):

What you have posted is no way a batch file that WinSCP would generate. You must have manually altered the script (and broke it).

A [batch file that WinSCP would generate](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_automation#generating) would look like:

```
@echo off

"C:\Program Files (x86)\WinSCP\WinSCP.com" ^
  /log="C:\writable\path\to\log\WinSCP.log" /ini=nul ^
  /command ^
    "open sftp://XXXXXXXXXXXXXX/ -hostkey=""ssh-rsa XXXX gk:op:09:n8:00:44:32:00:11:bn:mm:pp:45:bh:03:ea""" ^
    "lcd C:\Users\007\Documents\testdata" ^
    "cd /XXX/XXX/XXX/testdata" ^
    "put *" ^
    "exit"

set WINSCP_RESULT=%ERRORLEVEL%
if %WINSCP_RESULT% equ 0 (
  echo Success
) else (
  echo Error
)

exit /b %WINSCP_RESULT%
```

---

An example of WinSCP dialog for generating a batch file for a file transfer:

[image]